# Rock, paper, scissors: variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game. When I play I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File: "C:\Users\16033\Documents\dev\Game2Python\rockpaperscissors2.py", line 37, in <module>
comp answer = comp_move()
File "C:\Users\16033\Documents\dev\Game2Python\rockpaperscissors2.py"» line 22, 1n comp_move
return comp_answer
UnboundLocalError: local variable ‘comp answer’ referenced before assignment
```

What's causing it? I don't understand the error.

```
import random


score = 0
total_games = 0
computer = [random.randint(1,3)]

def intro_text():
    print("welcome to RPS")
    print("Type in your answer below:")

def comp_move():
    if computer == 1:
        print("Computer used Rock!")
        comp_answer = 1
    if computer == 2:
        print("Computer used Paper!")
        comp_answer = 2
    if computer == 3:
        print("Computer used Scissors")
        comp_answer = 3
    return comp_answer

def player_move():
    move = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, [S]cissors")
    if move == "R":
        print("You used Rock!")
        player_answer = 1
    elif move == "P":
        print("You used Paper!")
        player_answer = 2
    elif move == "S":
        print("You used Scissors!")
        player_answer = 3
    return player_answer
    
comp_answer = comp_move()
player_answer = player_move()

def analyze_moves(score):
    if player_answer == comp_answer:
        print("Draw!")
    elif player_answer < comp_answer:
        print("You lose!")
    elif player_answer > comp_answer:
        print("You win!")
        score += 1
    return score
    

while True:
    total_games +=1
    intro_text()
    analyze_moves(score)
    
    print("would you like to play again?")
    play_again = input()
    if play_again == "n":
        break

print("Thanks for playing! you won " + str(score) + " out of " +  str(total_games) + " games.")
```

Comment: `computer` is a list, so it will never be equal to any of the numbers.

Comment: Why did you put `[]` around it when you assigned `computer`?

Comment: You should get a new computer move and player move every time through the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because `computer` is never `1` or `2` or `3`. Take a look at this

```
computer = [random.randint(1,3)] # You are using [] and declaring a list
```

So in your function `comp_move()` the condition `computer == 1 # or any int` will never succed.

Also the `if` statement is redundant, you should instead do

```
computer = random.randint(1,3) # this is an int 1 <= int <=3 not a list
# your code ...
def comp_move():
    comp_answer = computer
    return comp_answer # or just return computer
```

Comment: shouldn't `computer = random.randint(1,3)` be inside `comp_move()` as a new number has to be generated everytime?

Comment: Yes, there is no meaning in declaring a global variable and returning it inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in the code:

1. The `computer` var is a list and you are comparing it with int's 1, 2, 3, by that the `comp_answer` var is not getting assign.
2. The `comp_answer` and `player_answer` after the first iteration of the `while` loop is not changing so you will have the same values on each iteration.

You can try

```py
import random

score = 0
total_games = 0



def intro_text():
    print("welcome to RPS")
    print("Type in your answer below:")


def comp_move():
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    
    if computer == 1:
        print("Computer used Rock!")
    elif computer == 2:
        print("Computer used Paper!")
    elif computer == 3:
        print("Computer used Scissors")
    
    return computer


def player_move():
    move = input("[R]ock, [P]aper, [S]cissors")
    if move == "R":
        print("You used Rock!")
        player_answer = 1
    elif move == "P":
        print("You used Paper!")
        player_answer = 2
    elif move == "S":
        print("You used Scissors!")
        player_answer = 3
    return player_answer



def analyze_moves(score):
    comp_answer = comp_move()
    player_answer = player_move()
    if player_answer == comp_answer:
        print("Draw!")
    elif player_answer < comp_answer:
        print("You lose!")
    elif player_answer > comp_answer:
        print("You win!")
        score += 1
    return score


while True:
    total_games += 1
    intro_text()
    analyze_moves(score)

    print("would you like to play again?")
    play_again = input()
    if play_again == "n":
        break

print("Thanks for playing! you won " + str(score) + " out of " + str(total_games) + " games.")
```

Comment: this only solves his error, which was comparing a `<list>` with an `int`. this code will not generate random numbers for every game. you have to have your `computer = random.randint(1, 3)` inside `comp_move()`. else, it is highly redundant as having no operation inside the function, and just returning a global variable seems meaningless.

Comment: That's right I fixed the code accordingly.

Comment: This was very helpful! between you and priyanshul I was able to get it running correctly. Just to let you know, I did only put `computer = random.randint(1, 3)` in `comp_move` other wise it would tell you what the computer chose before you choose :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. If you can vote up and mark the answer that will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers have already been posted which answer your question. However, I feel that your `comp_move()` is highly redundant, so I'll provide a much better(shorter) way to do it.

```py
options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

def comp_move():
    computer = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(f"Computer used {options[computer - 1]}!")
    return computer
```